# flow_from_dataframe doesn't work when I save dataframe then read it back

Tags: keras

When I read a CSV file then split data to train and test data from that dataframe. After that, I'm using flow_from_dataframe to create data generator, that works. But when I try to save train and test data to CSV file because I don't want to change train and test data every time and read it back then using flow_from_dataframe, it doesn't work anymore. Here is my code:

```
df = parser.labels_df
df.head()

"""Dividing dataset into train, val and test for validation later"""
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.1)
train_data = train_data.reset_index(drop=True)
test_data = test_data.reset_index(drop=True)

train_data.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/train_data.csv', index=False)
tmp_train_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/train_data.csv')

train, val = train_test_split(tmp_train_data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

train = train.reset_index(drop=True)
val = val.reset_index(drop=True)

def data_generator(train, val, test):
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                        horizontal_flip = True,  
                                        height_shift_range= 0.1, 
                                        width_shift_range=0.1, 
                                        rotation_range=5, 
                                        zoom_range=0.15)

    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train,
        directory='/content/vinbigdata/train/',
        x_col="image_id",
        y_col="class_name",
        batch_size=16,
        target_size=(512,512),
        classes = parser.labels,
        class_mode='categorical')

    validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=val,
        directory='/content/vinbigdata/train/',
        x_col="image_id",
        y_col="class_name",
        batch_size=16,
        target_size=(512,512),
        classes = parser.labels,
        class_mode='categorical')

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=test,
        directory='/content/vinbigdata/train/',
        x_col="image_id",
        y_col="class_name",
        batch_size=16,
        target_size=(512,512),
        classes = parser.labels,
        class_mode='categorical')
    
    return train_generator, validation_generator, test_generator

train_generator, validation_generator, test_generator = data_generator(train, val, test_data)
```

Results:

```
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 6 classes.
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 6 classes.
Found 790 validated image filenames belonging to 6 classes.
```

The test_data I didn't save to CSV so it works.
The train, val, test have data:

```
print("Found {} samples for training".format(len(train)))
print("Found {} samples for validation".format(len(val)))
print("Found {} samples for test".format(len(test_data)))
```

Result:

```
Found 5687 samples for training
Found 1422 samples for validation
Found 790 samples for test
```

Comment: In your code, you called this : ` data_generator(train, val, test_data)`. Where did you define train, val and test data? Please add these definition to your code in your question.

Comment: @Kaveh Sorry, I just edited. Test data I keep from: 
test_data = test_data.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: It is likely the saved file, and the original one, differ. Compare `train_data.head()` and `train.head()` and also `train_data.dtypes` and `train.dtypes` to see if something differ.

Comment: `train_data` and `train` actually are different because I split `train` from `train_data`. And the data type of both is the same.

Comment: I don't care about the order in `train` or `val`. One thing I care about is why the data read from the saved CSV file doesn't work like the first one before save is `test_data`

Comment: OK. I meant check for data for something may be weird. Not the data order. For example maybe image name column in both of them is in string type, but in the saved one, it is something like "image.jpg.png", (with another extension).

Comment: All image name in the saved is the same :( That is the problem. I don't know why they look exactly the same but the saved one doesn't work :((